# Why does my character move up forever when he jumps with this code?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick

I've been doing some stupid stuff in Slick2D+LWJGL and I've run into a problem.
I press the UP arrow and my character continues to go up until I let go :/
Here's the code:

```
if (inp.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP) && !jumping) {
    jumping = true;
    velY=-0.4f;
} else {
    jumping = false;
    velY=0.2f;
}
```

No idea what's happening :/ Help?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this code is called once every frame. What is likely happening is that while you hold down the up arrow, you are constantly toggling the state of `jumping`, which means you take the positive branch of the `if` every *even* frame and the negative branch every *odd* frame.

That also means you constantly toggle the velocity between `-0.4` and `0.2`. Every frame you presumably process that velocity and offset the player by it; however, because your upwards velocity exceeds your downwards velocity, you'll have a net upwards movement.

For example:

- On frame 0 you starting hold up. That sets your velocity to -0.4 (and `jumping` to `true`) and then you add that velocity to the player's position, giving you a delta in of Y of -0.4.
- The next frame you are still holding up, but `jumping` is now true, so you take the negative branch, setting velocity to 0.2 and jumping to `false`. When you apply velocity to position, you have a net delta of `-0.4 + 0.2 = -0.2`.
- Now, the third frame you are still holding up but `jumping` is now false, so you take the positive branch, set velocity to -0.4 and jumping to true. When you apply velocity to position you have a net delta of `-0.2 - 0.4 = -0.6`.

That's why your player always moves up.

To fix this, you could restructure the condition as follows:

```
if (inp.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
  if (!jumping) {
    jumping = true;
    velY=-0.4f;
  }
} else {
  jumping = false;
  velY=0.2f;
}
```

This means that if the up key is held, you start jumping if you have not already. If the up key is *not* held, you cancel the jump.

Comment: Seems like the same thing is happening :/ As I hold down up, my "character" continues to go up.

Comment: Do you ever set the velocity elsewhere? If you don't reduce it to zero over time, of course he will still go up since you imparted a constant velocity.

Comment: Use your debugger to examine the state of the data every frame (or print it to a log file). That should help you diagnose what other areas of the code are problematic.

Comment: You can also search this site for "2D jumping" and similar to find other questions discussing how to implement a good jump. You may find them better suited than your current approach.

Comment: I switched `velY=0.2f;` to `velY+=0.001f;` and it works how I wanted it to :) 0.1f or even 0.01f is extremely fast for some reason :/ but whatever, Thanks a bunch for the help :)